# Is there an explicit or recursive formula for the sequence 1,-3, 5, -7, 9...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an explicit or recursive formula for the sequence 1,-3, 5, -7, 9...

A fifth grader could probably explain the rule in words, but I'm challenged in doing so mathematically. I noticed that the 'second differences' are always 4, possibly implying an underlying quadratic, but utterly baffled by the sign-flipping. Any ideas? Thank you. VJ

Comment: It's the odd numbers but every number on even position is negative, do you know what the formula is for $1,-1,1,-1,1,...$

Comment: You could [look it up in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C-3%2C5%2C-7%2C9&sort=&language=&go=Search).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1=1$.
$$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\times(2n-1)$$
or
$$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}(|a_{n-1}|+2)$$

Comment: @Holo Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, this helps tremendously, but I have one remaining question regarding the answer- it seems picayune, but bothers me just a (tiny) bit.  The first formula works in all cases, but the second formula, with the absolute value, does not seem to produce an answer for the first term. I'm assuming, since the first term is given as a-sub 1 =1 that that does not matter... Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: The second formula is defined recursively, that means it needs a starting value. Consider $a_1=2.$ Then $a_2=-4, a_3=6$... Also, if we don't give a starting value, then one can not find out the value of any of the terms. Try using the second formula without $a_1=1$